# iOS memory management about NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any different between

```
NSString * str = @"123";
```

and

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"123"];
```

from compiler's aspect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically yes; in implementation detail, probably not.

In the first case, the compiler creates a constant string and assigns a pointer to it to the variable `str`.  You do not own the string.

In the second case, the compiler creates a constant string (as before) but this time it is used by the run time as a parameter in initialising another string that you do own (because the second string was created using `alloc`).

That's the end of the stuff you *need* to know.

However, there is a lot of optimisation that goes on.  Because `NSStrings` are immutable, you'll find that `initWithString:` actually just returns the parameter.  Normally, it would retain the parameter before returning it to you (because you are expecting to own it) but literal strings have a special retainCount (`INT_MAX` I think) to stop the run time from ever trying to deallocate them.  So in practice, your second line of code produces identical results to the first.

This incidentally, is why it is incorrect top say the string is autoreleased in the first case, because it isn't.  It's just a constant string with a special retain count.

But you can and should safely ignore the implementation detail and just remember, you don't own the string in the first case, but you do own it in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of differences. The most important is that you own the second string so you're responsible for releasing it (as is the case whenever you get an object from the `init` family of methods).

Another is that the former creates a string literal, and if you make a new string with the same literal, they will be pointers to the same object. If you do this:

```
NSString * str1 = @"123"; 
NSString * str2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"123"];
NSString * str3 = @"123";
```

Then `str1 == str2` is false, but `str1 == str3` is true. (Of course, the string content is the same, so `isEqual:` will return true. Also, while this does make for faster comparison, you probably shouldn't use it because it's an implementation detail and could in theory change in the future).

Comment: `str1 == str2` is quite likely true, but only because of an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the first case you do not own the string and you are not responsible to release it.

In the second case, instead, you are calling `alloc` thus you become the owner of the object and you must call `release` on it when you have done, otherwise it will become a memory leak.

In general, if the method you use to get your object contains "new","alloc","copy" or "mutableCopy" then you are the owner of the object and you are responsible to release it.

Check the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first is assignment of an NSString, and in the second the `alloc` (which means you need to release it in some way later) and `initWithString:` method are getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , first statement creates an autorelease object.
Second one creates an object occupying some memory and you have to release it after using it.

Comment: In the first case the constant string is not autoreleased.

Comment: ok got it, it is not autorelaased. But if it would be 

NSString * str = [NSString StringWithString:@"123"];
Then It must be autoreleased right?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Since @"123" is immutable, you might just get a pointer to it back.

Answer (score 0):

The main important difference about memory (your question title) is:
when you do:

```
NSString* myString =  @"my text";
```

you are allocating an object of **NSConstantString** type.

The difference with NSString is:
NSConstantString is **statically allocate**, while NSString is **dynamically allocated**.

Comment: Almost;  in fact, `str` will end up referring tot he same statically allocated string as an implementation detail. `initWithString:` will see that `@"123"` is an immutable string and will simply return it.